# Is the set of all quadratic, real-valued functions a vector space?

Tags: functions, vector-spaces, quadratics

I know there are already some similar questions but I still do not understand how to prove that the set of all quadratic functions defined on the real line is a vector space.

The question I got was: "Consider the quadratic, real-valued functions defined on the real line. Prove that it is a vector space. Of what dimension? Produce a basis."

If I read the exercise I would assume that it is a vector space.

But how is it possible since a quadratic function like ax^2+bx+c can be never closed under scalar multiplication I think because if the scalar would be zero I do not get a quadratic function as result.

Cheers for any help or hint.

Comment: Why wouldn't $\lambda \times (ax^2+bx+c)=\lambda a x^2+\lambda bx +\lambda c$ still be quadratic?

Comment: By multiplying $a x^2+b x+c$ by $0$, you get $0 x^2+0x+0$, which could be argued to be in the space of quadratic functions. But you need to define quadratic functions more precisely to make any argument more rigorous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's be careful by what we mean by a quadratic function. Typically, one defines a quadratic function $p:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ as a function given by the equation $p(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ for some $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a \neq 0$. If we enforce the condition $a \neq 0$, then the set of quadratics are not a subspace of ${C}(\mathbb{R})$, since it would not contain the zero function.

If we don't enforce this condition and allow $a=0$, then it is indeed a subspace of ${C}(\mathbb{R})$, since clearly we have closure under scalar multiplication and addition. The dimension is $3$ with the canonical basis $\{1, x, x^2\}$. However, in this case, it is not ideally described as the set of quadratic functions, but rather the set of polynomials of degree $\leq 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Your doubt is a legitimate one, but I'm sure that whoever created that exercise had in mind that a “quadratic function” is *any* function from $\mathbb R$ into itself of the type $x\mapsto ax^2+bx+c$. In articular, if $a=b=c=0$, then you get the null function.

Comment: Thank you all for your useful help!